# How to add more toppings to frozen pizza?

Tags: baking, pizza, italian-cuisine

I generally buy frozen Pizza Margherita in store for making a quick lunch if I am running out of time. However, I don't really like the taste of the baked Pizza because it is just Tomato and Cheese. I am a vegetarian and I would like to add toppings but when? Should I directly add veggies on frozen pizza and put it in the oven or let the frozen pizza bake for a few minutes and then add the toppings ? Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 7):

The method I've used to add toppings to frozen pizza is- use frozen toppings. For example, green peppers are in my opinion a great addition to pizza. I usually keep frozen green peppers and other pizza-worthy vegetables for use with many things, and frozen pizza is one of them. This way, I simply add the toppings to the pizza before baking and viola! Easy, simple, and much more tasty frozen pizzas.

Answer (score 6):

I do this quite frequently, as well as making my own pizzas. Most pizzas will cook in approximately 20 minutes, so it is absolutely fine to put any of your favourite toppings on right from the start of cooking. It may be beneficial for some foods which are more likely to char (such as broccoli or thinly sliced ham) to be either dipped in water first or covered with a little cheese to insulate them against the heat and stop them from drying out.

Comment: Ditto this exactly. I add toppings (sliced raw onion / mushroom / bell pepper / broccoli / asparagus..., shredded or sliced meats) and then some extra cheese. Bake for the normal amount of time and it's fine. The only thing you have to be careful of is not adding too many "wet" vegetables as these can make the middle of the pizza end up a bit soggy.

Comment: You might find the onion nicer if you fry it first, then add it to the pizza near the end of the cooking time. It also has the added benefit of driving the water out - raw onions are one of the main offenders for soggy pizza.

Comment: I love caramelised onions on a pizza! Especially if a tiny bit of sugar and a healthy glug of balsamic vinegar are added shortly before the end of frying!

Answer (score 3):

One of the best toppings for a pizza is egg, just don't put it on at the start. Let the pizza cook for about 12 minutes then crack the egg on top and place back in for another 6-8 minutes. This should leave the egg runny, but if you don't want it like this then just leave for a little longer.

Onions and peppers are good toppings as well and they can go on right from the start.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time with my friend the pizza and I have somehow never considered eggs as a potential topping. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

For vegetarian options, it depends on what you want to add.  Pickled jalapeño slices go right on top before you bake it, and they add just the right amount of zing to a bland pizza (cut them in half or even quarters if you're timid).  Spinach or kale can be washed, chopped, and added right on top, too, before the bake. Unless you slice green peppers or onions quite thin, microwave them for 45 sec. before you put them on. (Red peppers cook faster.) Fresh mushrooms sound fantastic, but raw ones will make a frozen pizza soggy, so do stir-fry them first for 1-2 min. in oil or butter and then add them before the bake. Fresh tomatoes should go on after the bake, unless they are anemic winter or strip-mined tomatoes, in which case, you should dice them, press the extra juice out, and scatter them before the bake in a wide circe, avoiding the middle. Olives can go on either before or after.  As my dad says, dress up frozen pizza? I dress it up in a tuxedo!

Answer (score 0):

Roasted veggies yesterday. I'll reheat them before topping the frozen pizza, then use the regular cooking time.

Answer (score 0):

My granddaughter will only eat
cheese pizza with mushrooms and black olives so I thinly slice the mushrooms and olives and spread them out over the frozen pizza. Then on the other half, I thinly slice red onion and separate into rings and scatter on that half, along with pepperoni. I think sprinkle a little garlic powder and black pepper over the entire pizza, then scatter a thin layer of mozzarella all over. I bake at 425 for 20-22 minutes, rotating the pan at 10 minutes and it’s never soggy and the crust is crisp and the cheese bubbly and slightly brown. I cool for a couple of minutes, then slice and serve

Answer (score -1):

Chop up lunch meats , leftover fully cooked chicken or hamburger, Kroger has a frozen bag of peppers and onions diced and your very simple plain pizza just became something from the heyday of pizza when flavors were in incredible.add it all at the beginning cook at 400 for roughly twenty minutes.